# Prolog check if two values are member of a list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn Prolog and I asked myself if it is possible to have the following predicates:

- member_of which is true, if the given element is part of the provided list
- member_8 which is true, if 8 is part of the provided list
- member_7_or_8 which is true, if 7 or 8 are part of the provided list
- member_7_and_8 which is true, if 7 and 8 are poart of the provided list

I was able to solve all the predicates except the last one. Can you give me a hint on how to solve that?

```
member_of(E,[E|_]). 
member_of(E,[_|R]):-member(E,R).

member_8([8|R]).
member_8([_|R]):-member_8(R).

member_7_or_8([7|R]).
member_7_or_8([8|R]).
member_7_or_8([_|R]):-member_7_or_8(R).
```

Comment: Don't you think that **member_8** is a particular case of **member_of** ? You should use **member_of**  to solve **member_8**. For **member_7_or_8** take a look at the signification of ';' in Prolog

Comment: You're right. I could have used member_of, but to learn explicitly how Prolog works, I decided to implement different predicates for those "tasks". Thanks for the hint with the ';', but as far as I can see, the ';' let's you implement 'or'. This does not help me solving my problem, or am I overseeing sth.?

Comment: I don't agree. If **member_of** works well, you MUST use it to solve the rest of your assigment, so ';' and ',' are your friends !

Comment: Ah, now I got your point. Sometimes...
So I came up with
   member_7_and_8(L):-member_of(7,L),member_of(8,L).

Comment: You got it ! same design for member_7_ or_8.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a "helper" predicate which allows you to check wether an element is member of a given list. With the help of that predicate, it is possible to check for existence of multiple elements. E.g.

```
member_of(E,[E|_]). 
member_of(E,[_|R]):-member(E,R).
member_7_and_8(L):-member_of(7,L),member_of(8,L).
```